# what is the most efficient way to add a new attribute with default value to existing dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

we already have got a table with 100000 records, we wanted to add a new attribute to all items with a default value.

CLI or write a program with .net, python to do the batch update?

Comment: Batch update is not directly supported by DynamoDB. You'll need to update items individually in a loop whether you do it with CLI or programmatically.

Comment: Right - the `BatchWriteItem` operation allows to send a number of `PutItem` operations in one request, but those can only replace entire items - they can't update existing items to add an attribute like you wanted to do. For this you need individual `UpdateItem` requests - and there is no "batched" version of it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no **efficient** way to do what you want to do. Any way you do this will first need to figure out all the records' keys (probably by reading all of them), and then iterate over all these keys with an `UpdateItem` request (there is no batched version of that, unfortunately) to add the new attribute.

It's also important to note that although the `UpdateItem` operation may only add a small attribute to a possibly large existing item - you will pay for the rewrite of the *entire* item. You'll basically be paying for rewriting your entire data set.

See a similar question where I gave a more detailed answer here: [need to add TTL to a 3bln+ record ddb table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952692/need-to-add-ttl-to-a-3bln-record-ddb-table/59964669#59964669)